# What is the 'last_name, first_name' format called?

Tags: names, lists, surnames

Is there a name for the format of listing names by 'Last name, first name'?  For example, how names were listed in phone books when those existed. Ex: this list of names is sorted (blank style):

Goodman, Leo
Herman, Bob
Smith, John

Comment: Simply 'alphabetical order of surname'.

Comment: Or “last name first.”

Comment: What year are you living in? Phone books still exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a well-defined term for this type of list. There first needs to be some clarification of what first name and last name mean - they do not always conform to the presumed model of given name (personal name) and family name (surname).

I have always used the term ***surname-ordered*** list in my computer programming. White Pages directories generally describe their own sorting simply as alphabetical, as do most [dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/White+page).

Sorting by *surname* has some pitfalls - a number of countries and cultures do fit the standard FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME naming structure. Spanish and Portuguese names often have one or two personal names and one or two family names (such as [Vicente Yáñez Pinzón](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicente_Y%C3%A1%C3%B1ez_Pinz%C3%B3n)). Chinese and a number of other Asian countries are usually written with the family name first (such as [Liu Xiaobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Xiaobo)). Some exceptions to the standard sorting methods of names is described nicely in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSUR#Sort_by_surname). For these reasons, sorting by LAST_NAME can be tricky if LAST_NAME is not a well-defined and independent field.

Comment: +1 for pointing out arbitrariness of the idea of 'last name', and also for linking to Liu Xiaobo

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is called "Lexicographic Order"